# game map in ruby for text based rpg

Tags: ruby, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have question about generating a game map in ruby for text based rpg.
I've researched and came up with two possible options: 2d array and matrix.

My question is which one would be more suitable for implementation of these features:

- at generation the size of the map is defined
- each tile represents a geounit
- a geonuit is randomly assigned a name and type (housing unit, police station etc) => this would enable different map for each game
- random assignment of types must take into account the proximity rule

The proximity rule would mean a certain number of units that must be between two geounits of the same type. To make the game play harder, for example two police stations must be 10 geounits apart. Of course this would mean in any direction (possibly also diagonally).

Thank you,

regards,

seba

Comment: The answer so far will be "it depends" - mainly on complexity of your generators and needing to navigate and find types of tile in the game. In fact neither 2D array nor matrix are going to be more than a simple start into the data structures and processing you will need for your game (even the generator and proximity rules are going to make this an interesting and hard problem). I suggest just take an initial data type (my gut instinct says matrix) and start implementing. Ask here, or maybe  http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ when you get stuck into one of the tough problems.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll definitely start solve problems as I go. I was only afraid I'd choose the "wrong" approach and that would cause too many issues later on. Regarding the matrix, can it be dynamically expanded? If I go for the limitless world map that generates when needed.
I always wanted to build such a game and this would also offer enough learning challenges:)

Comment: Whilst you can re-size and re-shape matrices, so it won't be a problem if you have relatively small maps, that's an awkward and expensive operation. Obviously games with very many "tiles" like Minecraft manage it very well. I'm not sure what a good data structure is for an infinite growing map - I'd guess it is multi-layered with a dynamic array or hash of large-scale co-ordinates containing matrices with the fine detail for some block size.